# Running playwright in headed mode C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, playwright

Is there a way to run playwright tests that inherit from PageTest class  in headed mode from visual studio in order to be able to use the VS debug mode?

The following option is what I did initially:

```
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
{Headless = false});
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.GotoAsync("testurl");
```

However this approach adds several lines of repeated code.

Instead of the above approach I started inheriting from PagetTest so that I would not need to instantiate the browser and the context. The problem with this is that Im not able to run the tests in headed mode directly from visual studio.

The following steps allow me to run the tests in headed mode with a playwright debugging window:

In a terminal set : $env:PWDEBUG=1
Then run the test using: dotnet test --filter "Name~TestName"

This runs in head mode but with a playwright built in debugging window. This only lets me ‘step over’ or run. Also I cant use things like the immediate window to evaluate things while Im designing my tests.

Is there a way to run in headed mode directly from visual studio so that I can use the VS debugger and immediate window?

Comment: Visual Studio uses Playwright tests in Headed mode. Can it not get the data?

Comment: Not As far as I know, at least in the situation when you inherit from the PageTest class and want to run the tests in headed mode directly from visual studio

Answer (score 3):

What I've done is add a runsettings file to visual studio called, for example, `test.runsettings` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
        <HEADED>1</HEADED>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

Then, as long as VS chooses that runsettings file (see Test > Configure Run Settings in the menu) you should start getting HEADED mode

Comment: Can this just be added to the app config or does it need to be a seperate test.runsettings file? Where does this file need to be placed?

Comment: Either put it in the root of the solution to be found automatically, or someplace specific and set the location using Test -> Configure Run Settings -> Select solution wide runsettings file.  More details are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022